# Font-Family not being imported

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to use a font called "Patua One" but the changes are not showing when I add the attribute inside the css.

Here is my css code:

```
.p1{
font-family: "Patua One";
font-size: 70px;
color: #1B423E;
}
```

This is what my import looks like:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'patua_oneregular';
src: url('patuaone-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('patuaone-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('patuaone-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('patuaone-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('patuaone-regular-webfont.svg#patua_oneregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

If you are wondering, src: url('patuaone-regular-webfont') is located in my webroot and it includes all of those files.

This is my root directory
[image: Here is my root directory:]

Then inside the webfontkit are these files:

[image]

Inside the style.css is the @import css I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `font-family` should have consistent value when importing and using.

Also, you have not given correct path of font files.

It should be:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'patua_oneregular';
    src: url('../webfontkit-patuaone/patuaone-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../webfontkit-patuaone/patuaone-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../webfontkit-patuaone/patuaone-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../webfontkit-patuaone/patuaone-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../webfontkit-patuaone/patuaone-regular-webfont.svg#patua_oneregular') format('svg');
```

AND

```
.p1{
    font-family: 'patua_oneregular';
}
```

Comment: I did just that, but it's still not reflecting any changes.

Comment: @user3278616 check browser console. is it giving any error related to file path??

Comment: I'll check it out. For the mean time, I added pictures of how the folders look like above.

Answer (score 0):

At your import you say `:font-family: 'patua_oneregular';` and at css `font-family: "Patua One";`

Make those the same, either way.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
font-family: "Patua One";
```

at both places and make sure it should be be the same name mentioned inside the font when you open the font file on font viewer, if its not the same sometimes it does not work in IE.